# How to fix `Error: unknown filesystem Entering rescue mode... grub rescue` on ubuntu 21.10

Tags: ubuntu, boot, partitioning, grub, grub2

I was working with my PC that it hanged and I pressed the Shut Down button until PC turned off. After that when I wanted to turn on the computer I got this error:

> error: unkown filesystem Entering rescue mode... grub rescue>

I tried command `ls` resulting in:

> (hd0) (hd0,msdos5) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1)

and `set prefix=(hd0,msdos1)/boot/grub` the result was empty

Then I tried command `insmod normal` resulting in:

> error: unknow filesystem

I tried to boot from USB, and got this error:

> GRUB loading. Welcome to GRUB!
> error: symbol 'grub_calloc' not found.
> entering rescue mode...
> grub rescue>

**I have some important data on my PC.**

Is there any way to fix the issue without losing data?

**Update:**

I boot Ubuntu20.04 with NTFS partition and then tried to live boot and this time ubuntu launched!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ic68a.jpg)